# Java Matrix4f.transform equivalent in GLM?

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

In OpenGL for Java, Matrix4f has a transform() method. I am trying to look at an example using this, but want to translate it into using GLM. But I cannot find an equivalent to transform() in GLM, nor do I grasp what transform() really does.

For example:

In Java:

```
Vector4f direction = new Vector4f(x, y, z, 1);
Matrix4f rotationMatrix = new Matrix4f();
… set rotationMatrix …
Matrix4f.transform(rotationMatrix, direction, direction);
```

With GLM in C++:

```
vec4 direction = vec4(x, y, z, 1);
mat4 rotationMatrix = mat4();
… set rotationMatrix …
??? What to use instead of transform() ???
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [GLM](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/index.html) provides the `*`-operator. It can be used similar the operators in [OpenGL Shading Language (GLSL)](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/index_gl.php) e.g.:

```cpp
vec4 direction = vec4(x, y, z, 1.0f);
mat4 rotationMatrix = mat4(1.0f);

direction = rotationMatrix * direction;
```

Note, if you want to construct an [Identity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix) then you'e to pass a single scalar (1.0) to the constructor of `mat4` (e.g. `mat4(1.0f)`). `mat4()` constructs an uninitialized matrix.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I did try the *-operator before, but it was the missing 1.0f in the constructor of the mat4 that did the trick.